# Invite friends through Facebook PhoneGap plugin gives SECURITY_ERR error

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

After I invite my friends with PhoneGap Facebook plugin, I always get this error:

> 08-22 11:24:43.549: E/Web Console(3810): Uncaught Error: SECURITY_ERR: DOM Exception 18 at file:///android_asset/www/js/libary.js:778

My code is as follows:

```
function initializa_db()
{
   database = new DataBase;
    db = window.openDatabase("enquete", "1.0", "Enquete", 500000);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am very confused with what your asking but I imagine it's because you didn't add the permission in your android manifest if this is the case, you should add this line of code to your android manifest

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```